# How to provision a CloudFront distribution with an ACM Certificate using Cloud Formation

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, ssl-certificate, amazon-cloudfront, aws-cloudformation

I am attempting to set a certificate in my CloudFrontDistribution using Cloud Formation.

My certificate has been issued via Certificate Manager. It has been approved, and I have validated that the certificate works by manual configuration directly through the CloudFront console.

Within my CloudFormation template,  I have attempted to use both the *Identifier* and *ARN* values associated with the certificate in the IamCertificateId property:

```
"ViewerCertificate" : {
  "IamCertificateId" : "********",
  "SslSupportMethod": "sni-only"
}
```

But in both cases I receive the following error:

```
The specified SSL certificate doesn't exist, isn't valid, or doesn't include a valid certificate chain.
```

Reading the docs for the [DistributionConfig Complex Type](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/APIReference/DistributionConfigDatatype.html#DistributionConfigDatatype_Elements) it looks like there is a 'ACMCertificateArn' property, but this does not seem to work via CloudFormation.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It maybe the case that cloudformation doesn't support acm for CloudFront, yet.  Typically there is a lag until cloudformation supports new features.

Comment: I suspect this to be the case. Sad.

Comment: Maybe you can consider marking my response which includes updated information as correct answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Cloudformation added this property but it is not documented. You can use like this easily:

```
"ViewerCertificate": {
            "SslSupportMethod": "sni-only",
            "AcmCertificateArn": "CERTIFICATE_ARN"
}
```

Be aware that the certificate must be created in us-east-1 region, if not it won't be accepted.

Comment: I was going to test it first :)

Comment: Today they updated the documentation, now you can see the option: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cloudfront-distributionconfig-viewercertificate.html

Comment: Certificate should be in us-east-1 region.

Comment: thanks Çağatay! That was the problem. Hmm, now I have to split my stack a bit.

Comment: You may create the certificate in us-east-1 ACM and inject its ARN to any stack as string. You don't have to move your Cloudformation distribution resource to a stack in us-east-1.

Comment: oh I know- but then it isn't knitted together.

Answer (score 14):

(Update: As of [Aug 9 2016](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2016/08/aws-cloudformation-adds-support-for-aws-certificate-manager-amazon-ec2-service-auto-scaling-and-additional-updates/), AWS CloudFormation now supports ACM using the [`AcmCertificateArn`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cloudfront-distributionconfig-viewercertificate.html#cfn-cloudfront-distributionconfig-viewercertificate-acmcertificatearn) property, so the custom resource described below is no longer needed.)

---

Although the AWS::CloudFront::Distribution resource hasn't been updated to support the ACMCertificateArn property yet, it is currently possible to use a [custom CloudFormation resource](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) to implement the functionality needed using the AWS API directly until the official resource is updated.

See Ryan S. Brown's post, [CloudFormation To Build A CDN With (Free) Custom SSL](https://serverlesscode.com/post/acm-certificates-in-cloudformation/) where he describes his implementation of a `Custom::CloudFrontAcmAssociation` resource that associates an ACM certificate with a CloudFront distribution. The code is available at [`ryansb/acm-certs-cloudformation`](https://github.com/ryansb/acm-certs-cloudformation).

To use it, you need to make the CloudFormation resource's implementation available through an AWS Lambda function. Ryan's implementation is already published to a public S3 bucket, so you can reference this directly for testing purposes in your CloudFormation template like so:

```
"AcmAssociationFunction": {
  "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Function",
  "Properties": {
    "Handler": "cloudfront_associator.handler",
    "MemorySize": 128,
    "Runtime": "python2.7",
    "Code": {
      "S3Bucket": "demos.serverlesscode.com",
      "S3Key": "acm-certificate-resource-functions.zip"
    },
    "Role": {"Fn::GetAtt": ["ExecRole", "Arn"]},
    "Timeout": 300
  }
},
```

The `Lambda::Function` resource has a dependency on an IAM service Role and associated Policy to delegate the necessary permissions to the lambda function (the `ExecRole` reference above), so you need to add that too:

```
"ExecRolePolicies": {
  "Type": "AWS::IAM::Policy",
  "Properties": {
    "PolicyName": "ExecRolePolicy",
    "PolicyDocument": {
      "Version": "2012-10-17",
      "Statement": [
        {
          "Action": [
            "acm:*",
            "cloudfront:List*",
            "cloudfront:Get*",
            "cloudfront:UpdateDistribution"
          ],
          "Resource": [ "*" ],
          "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
          "Action": [ "logs:*" ],
          "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*",
          "Effect": "Allow"
        }
      ]
    },
    "Roles": [{"Ref": "ExecRole"}]
  }
},
"ExecRole": {
  "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
  "Properties": {
    "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
      "Version": "2012-10-17",
      "Statement": [
        {
          "Action": ["sts:AssumeRole"],
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Principal": {"Service": ["lambda.amazonaws.com"]}
        }
      ]
    }
  }
},
```

With the lambda function in place, finally add the `Custom::CloudFrontAcmAssociation` resource, providing the distribution ID, certificate ARN, and the custom resource lambda function's ARN:

```
"DistributionCertificateSetting": {
  "Type": "Custom::CloudFrontAcmAssociation",
  "Properties": {
    "DistributionId": {
      "Ref": "SiteCDN"
    },
    "CertificateArn": {
      "Ref": "AcmCertificate"
    },
    "ServiceToken": {
      "Fn::GetAtt": [
        "AcmAssociationFunction",
        "Arn"
      ]
    }
  }
},
```

tldr: copy all the code above into your CloudFormation template, set the appropriate `SiteCDN` and `AcmCertificate` properties (or edit the template with hard-coded values), and you should have a custom resource workaround until Amazon updates the official CloudFront resource.

Comment: Note several limitations to this approach: First, if you change any properties on the original CloudFront resource and update your CloudFormation stack, the ACM certificate will be removed after the update, since the base CloudFormation resource re-applies the original config. Second, when deleting the stack you may receive an error `The request failed because it didn't meet the preconditions in one or more request-header fields` (since it seems the base CloudFormation resource uses old `IfMatch` data and does not know about the updated ETag).

Answer (score 2):

I had a properly created certificate (public key 2048 bits), uploaded with the full chain. What was more challenging was the certificate was being used without problem in other AWS services (public ELB).

I was also passing the certificate Id (I had also tried with ARN but that's incorrect) correctly.

In my case, the problem was the certificate had been created with a "path": "/". After I uploaded a new certificate (with different name) with "Path": "/cloudfront/", everything worked without problem.

```
  aws iam upload-server-certificate \
    --server-certificate-name cert_cf \
    --certificate-body file://cert.crt \
    --private-key file://cert.key \
    --certificate-chain file://chain.pem \
    --path /cloudfront/
```

Answer (score 0):

Another valid approach I now use just creates the stack with the default certificate as long as the certificate is not issued (Inspired by [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/645359/conditional-property-in-aws-cloudformation))

It looks like

```
"Conditions": {
    "HasAcmCertificate": {
        "Fn::Equals": [
            {
                "Ref": "CloudfrontCertificateArn"
            },
            "NOT_ISSUED"
        ]
    }
},

...

"Cloudfront": {
    "Properties": {
        "DistributionConfig": {

            ...

            "ViewerCertificate": {
                "AcmCertificateArn": {
                    "Fn::If": [
                        "HasAcmCertificate",
                        {
                            "Ref": "AWS::NoValue"
                        },
                        {
                            "Ref": "CloudfrontCertificateArn"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "CloudFrontDefaultCertificate": {
                    "Fn::If": [
                        "HasAcmCertificate",
                        true,
                        {
                            "Ref": "AWS::NoValue"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "SslSupportMethod": {
                    "Fn::If": [
                        "HasAcmCertificate",
                        {
                            "Ref": "AWS::NoValue"
                        },
                        "sni-only"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "Type": "AWS::CloudFront::Distribution"
},
```

Answer (score -1):

Important to note capitalization of the field name for the cloudformation template.

**AcmCertificateArn** not ACMCertificateArn

**IamCertificateId** not IAMCertificateId

As a newbie to cloudformation I was pasting from the output of CLI queries which use different CamelCase.  Cloudformation would complain but spotting the different case was not immediately obvious to me.

Answer (score -2):

Took a few days but found the answer with some help from AWS support.

The information for:

```
"ViewerCertificate" : {
  "IamCertificateId" : "********",
  "SslSupportMethod": "sni-only"
}
```

is found using the CLI "aws iam list-server-certificates":

```
{
    "ServerCertificateId": "ASCAXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", 
    "ServerCertificateName": "devops.XXXXXXX.com", 
    "Expiration": "2017-03-10T15:00:33Z", 
    "Path": "/cloudfront/", 
    "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXX:server-certificate/cloudfront/devops.XXXXXXXXXXX.com", 
    "UploadDate": "2016-03-14T16:13:59Z"
},
```

Once I found that I added a variable cloudfront.CloudFrontCertificateId with the ServerCertificateId and fed it into the ViewerCertificate:

```
"ViewerCertificate" : {
  "IamCertificateId" : {{ cloudfront.CloudFrontCertificateId }},
  "SslSupportMethod": "sni-only"
}
```

Comment: This response covers how to use a certificate that you obtained from a third-party certificate authority and uploaded to the IAM certificate store, but the question above asked how to use a certificate managed by the new AWS Certificate Manager (ACM) service.