# How to configure "Instance Protection" over CloudFormation in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I need to set an "Instance Protection" property for the instances in my Auto Scaling Group using a CloudFormation template.

I normally do it in my AWS console like this: EC2 -> Auto Scaling Groups

[image]

But I can't seem to find it on CloudFormation [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-as-group.html)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It *can* be done using CloudFormation, but it's not easy.

CloudFormation *still* (as of 6/29/2020) does not officially support the Auto Scaling Instance Protection feature. This feature was [launched](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-instance-protection-for-auto-scaling/) back in 12/7/2015 and was unfortunately never integrated with CloudFormation.

For future reference, to confirm whether features have been integrated with CloudFormation, in addition to the [resource documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-as-group.html) you can also refer to the [CloudFormation release history](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/ReleaseHistory.html) to see if the desired feature is mentioned.

Other AWS SDKs tend to have more complete API coverage and are updated more frequently, so as a workaround you could create your AutoScaling Group using e.g. the AWS CLI [`create-auto-scaling-group`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/autoscaling/create-auto-scaling-group.html) command with the `--new-instances-protected-from-scale-in` flag.

If going outside CloudFormation to create your autoscaling group is not an option, another (more complicated) workaround would be to patch a Custom Resource on top of the existing CloudFormation resource to update the newly-created autoscaling group with the new feature setting using one of the updated SDKs. It works, but you'll need to create a lambda function and all supporting IAM roles and permissions, and hook them all together  into a custom resouce. For an example of how to do this to support another CloudFormation-unsupported feature (attaching ACM certificates to a CloudFront distribution), see my [SO answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36077024/2518355).

<s>Of course, it's easiest to wait for AWS to add official support for this feature to CloudFormation, as they eventually will.</s> **[Update 06/2020]** OK, after four years I've given up waiting. I'll admit I was wrong about this one!

Comment: Awesome. I needed this confirmation, I was thinking I didn't search enough. I guess I'll just wait. Thank you!

Comment: A year and a half after introduction of this feature, unfortunately still the correct answer.

Comment: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/autoscaling_group.html#protect_from_scale_in

Comment: is it supported now?

Comment: No, still nothing- I've updated my answer to admit I was wrong to predict it would ever eventually be supported!

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look like this is currently supported by CloudFormation.

If you look at the CFN documentation for Autoscaling, it has a element for [TerminationProtection](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-as-group.html#cfn-as-group-termpolicy), which is a list of strings.  I can't find a list of available options in the documentation, but when I use the CLI there doesn't seem to be anything related:

```
$> aws autoscaling describe-termination-policy-types
{
    "TerminationPolicyTypes": [
        "ClosestToNextInstanceHour", 
        "Default", 
        "NewestInstance", 
        "OldestInstance", 
        "OldestLaunchConfiguration"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is another factor in an Auto Scaling Group, however nothing relates the Instance Protection over the CLI.

Answer (score 2):

They finally added this feature on Oct 26, 2020.

[NewInstancesProtectedFromScaleIn](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-as-group.html#cfn-as-group-newinstancesprotectedfromscalein)