# Specific Auto-Scaling group Cloudformation AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, autoscaling

I have an auto scaling group in AWS so i can change stack size of instances created by CF.
However when i want to reduce the stack it will terminate random instances in the stack.

I need to know if its possible to reduce stack size in CF but leave specific instances in the stack running using the scaling group?

```
      "WebServerScaleUpPolicy" : {
  "Type" : "AWS::AutoScaling::ScalingPolicy",
  "Properties" : {
    "AdjustmentType" : "ChangeInCapacity",
    "AutoScalingGroupName" : { "Ref" : "AutoScalingServerGroup" },
    "Cooldown" : "60",
    "ScalingAdjustment" : "1"
  }
},
"WebServerScaleDownPolicy" : {
  "Type" : "AWS::AutoScaling::ScalingPolicy",
  "Properties" : {
    "AdjustmentType" : "ChangeInCapacity",
    "AutoScalingGroupName" : { "Ref" : "AutoScalingServerGroup" },
    "Cooldown" : "60",
    "ScalingAdjustment" : "-1"
  }
}
```

Any Help Appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into instance scale-in protection, as detailed in [this AWS blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-instance-protection-for-auto-scaling/) post.

I don't use CloudFormation so I'm not sure of the level of support it has for Autoscaling customisation, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35945827/how-to-configure-instance-protection-over-cloudformation-in-aws) post has a workaround that may work for you.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank You

Answer (score 3):

Look into [Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling Lifecycle Hooks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/lifecycle-hooks.html). As you'll see below, instance can be notified of the Scale In event and either prepare for termination or straight up cancel the scaling event.

[image]